# GUI to remember and perform terminal comands

Tags: linux

I would like a program that you can enter commands into and then name them.  It now gives you buttons that you can click that run the commands again.

Comment: I guess you are using bash at the moment? You can find that out with `echo $0`.

Comment: Do you want to see the output of each command? And also do you want to see whether each command failed or succeeded?

Comment: Yes I would like to see that.

Answer (score 1):

What you are searching for is called [alias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_%28command%29).

For example when you want the command `colorlist` to be the command `ls --color=always` you have to edit **~/.profile** and add

```
alias colorlist='ls --color=always'
```

### Running commands again

When you want to run commands again, you can press the <kbd>arrow up</kbd> button. That will show you the last command you have entered.

With <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> you can search your command history:

```
~$ git push           
bck-i-search: git
```

### Some more hints

I really recommend using zsh with the [Oh-My-ZSH plugin](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh). It gives you fuzzy command / path auto completion.

Comment: I would like it to have a GUI.

Answer (score 0):

edit a text file in emacs , one command by one line , possibly with comment lines for reminder .

```
/usr/bin/check-weather
# run every morning
# last result : rainy

/usr/bin/check-potato-price
# run every friday afternoon
# last result : 0.7 yuan per kilogramme
```

select the command and `M-| RET` "Meta-Pipe" (M-x shell-command-on-region RET) to launch the command . output will show in minibuffer or a dedicated "command output" buffer depending on length . there is also another option , yank the command into an empty line and use the `C-u M-| RET` variant , the selection will be replaced by command output .